# Console command to increase movement speed?

Tags: counter-strike-source

Is there a console command in Counter Strike: Source to increase the movement?
Or is there any other way by modifying game files?
Or is there at least a script for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this:

> To increase the maximum movement speed on your CS source server:
>
> - Open a console and type "sv_maxspeed"
> - The default value is 320 , you can change it to 500.